# Having separate executables for each project in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have a Visual Studio solution that contains two projects. One is a Windows Forms Application, and the other is a Console Application. When I build the solution, only one executable file is produced. Both projects have a different assembly name. How can I produce a different executable file for each project?

Comment: As far as I can see yes. And even when I right click the console application and manually "Build" it, it still does not output an executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you build the ***solution*** (<kbd>F6</kbd>), then both projects will build - but unless there is a dependency between them, they will build *separately* - i.e. you should be looking in two different locations:

```
TheConsoleApplication/bin/debug
TheWindowsApplication/bin/debug
```

or

```
TheConsoleApplication/bin/release
TheWindowsApplication/bin/release
```

(assuming default layouts; obviously adjust names to suit)